# How many Yugas are actually there - 4 or 18 as mentioned by Sage Agastya?

Tags: yuga, time, agastya

Yuga(m) is one of the basic units of time. Most Indian scriptures mention 4 yugas namely krita yuga, treta yuga, dvapara yuga and kali yuga. Each yuga has its own time scale and is regulated by years. In that case, now we are in kali yuga and after this again krita yuga will start.

Most of us know above said information however, this post is aimed to bring out the unknown information of yuga. Agathiyar in his book “Agathiyar Vaatha Sowmiyam” noted that there are 18 yugas as follows:

> கேளடா புலத்தியனே மைந்தா நீயுங்
>   kaeladaa Pulaththiyanae mainthaa neeyung
>   கெணிதமுள்ள யுகமதுதான் பதினெட்டுப்பா
>   kenithamulla yukamathuthaan pathinettappaa
>   ஆளடா வரியினுகம் ஈரேழுகோடி
>   aaladaa variyinukam eeraezhukoadi
>   அற்புதனார் யுகமதுதான் ஈரைந்துகோடி
>   arputhanaar yukamathuthaan eerainthukoadi
>   வாளடா தன்மயுகம் ஈராறுகோடி
>   vaaladaa thanmayukam eeraarukoadi
>   மகத்தான ராசியுகம் ஈரெட்டுகோடி
>   makaththaana raasiyukam eerettukkoadi
>   காலடா யுகமெல்லாஞ் சொல்லிவாரேன்
>   kaaladaa yukamellaanj sollivaaraen
>   கனமான வீராசன் நாலைந்துதானே
>   kanamaana veeraasan naalainthuthaanae.
>
> தானென்ற விண்ணதனில் ஈரெட்டுகோடி
>   thaanaenra vinnathanil eerattukkoadi
>   தருவான வாய்தனக்கு யுகம்ஏழுகோடி
>   tharuvaana vaaithanakku yukamaezhukoadi
>   மானென்ற மைனயுகம் இருமூன்றுகோடி
>   maanenra mainayukam irumoondrukoadi
>   மகத்தான மணிகள்யுகம் இருமூன்றுகோடி
>   makaththaana manikalyukam irumoondrukoadi
>   பானென்ற பணியிரதம் நான்குகோடி
>   paanenra paniyiratham naankukoadi
>   பதிவான விஸ்வாசன்யுகம் மூன்றுகோடி
>   pathivaana visvaasanyukam moonrukoadi
>   வானென்ற வாய்தன்யுகம் ஒருகோடியாகும்
>   vaanenra vaaithanyukam orukoadi yaakum
>   மார்க்கமுடன் திரேதாயுகந் தன்னைப்பாரே
>   maarkkamudan thiraethaayukan thannaippaarae.
>
> பாரடா திரேதாயுகம் அதனைக்கேளு
>   paaradaa thiraethaayukam athanaikkaelu
>   பதினேழு லக்ஷத்தொன் பதினாயிரமாம்
>   pathinaezu lakshaththon pathinaayiramaam
>   மேரடா கிரேதாயுகம் அதனைக்கேளு
>   maeradaa kiraethaayukam athanaikkaelu
>   விருபது லக்ஷத்தொன் பதினாயிரமாம்
>   virupathu lakshaththon pathinaayiramaam
>   தேரடா துவாபரயுகம் தனைக்கேளு
>   thaeradaa thuvaaparayukam thanaikkaelu
>   தீர்க்கமுடன் ஒன்பதுலக்ஷத்து ஒன்பதனாயிரமாம்
>   theerkkamudan onpathulakshaththu onpatha naayiramaam
>   காரடா கலியுகம் வெகு கடினமைந்தா
>   kaaradaa kaliyukam veku kadinamainthaa
>   கண்டுபார் லக்ஷத்து முப்பதினாயிரமாம்
>   kandupaar lakshaththu muppathinaayiramaam.

Agathiar’s above said poem gives information about 18 yugas as follows:

> variyin yuga comprises of 14 crore years,
>   arputhanar yuga comprises of 10 crore years,
>   thanma yuga comprises of 12 crore years,
>   raasi yuga comprises of 16 crore years,
>   sanya yuga comprises of 10 crore years,
>   veera raasan yuga comprises of 20 crore years,
>   vin yuga comprises of 16 crore years,
>   vaayu yuga comprises of 7 crore years,
>   maina yuga comprises of 6 crore years,
>   manikal yuga comprises of 6 crore years,
>   aththae yuga comprises of 19 crore years,
>   paniyiratha yuga comprises of 4 crore years,
>   visvaasana yuga comprises of 3 crore years,
>   vaaithan yuga comprises of 1 crore year,
>   thiraethaa (treta) yuga comprises of 17 lakhs and 9 thousand years,
>   kiraethaa (krita) yuga comprises of 20 lakh and 10 thousand years,
>   dvapara yuga comprises of 9 lakh and 9 thousand years and
>   most complicated kali yuga comprises of 1 lakh and 30 thousand years.

I read this on a website.

So how many Yugas are actually there - 4 or 18?

Comment: I've never heard of the Agathiyar Vaatha Sowmiyam, so I'm not sure if it's an authentic work by Agastya.

Comment: It is authentic he has said it in AGASTYA VADHA SOWMIYAM

Comment: What I'm saying is I don't know if Agastya Vadha Sowmiyam is an authentic work of Agastya.

Comment: Welcome to Hinduism.SE. What exactly is your question? You say: "this post is aimed to bring out the unknown information of yuga", "WHAT DO U THINK?" - Sorry, but this is a Q&A website. See [How do I ask a good question?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What types of questions should I avoid asking?](http://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)

Comment: @sv. Maybe he is just confirming that there are actually 18 Yugas like Agastya has apparently mentioned.

Comment: @Surya Yes, could be. OP should rephrase the question.